# Create new column with shared ID to randomly link two rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I am using R and working with this sample dataframe.

```
library(tibble)
library(stats)

set.seed(111)

conditions <- factor(c("1","2","3"))

df_sim <- 
  tibble::tibble(StudentID = 1:10,
         Condition = sample(conditions,
                            size = 10,
                            replace = T),
         XP = stats::rpois(n = 10,
                  lambda = 15))
```

This creates the following tibble.

| StudentID | Condition | XP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 |
| 3 | 3 | 16 |
| 4 | 3 | 12 |
| 5 | 1 | 22 |
| 6 | 3 | 16 |
| 7 | 1 | 18 |
| 8 | 3 | 8 |
| 9 | 2 | 14 |
| 10 | 1 | 17 |

I am trying create a new column in my dataframe called `DyadID`. The purpose of this column is to create a variable that is uniquely shared by two students in the dataframe — in other words, two students (e.g. Student 1 and Student 9) would share the same value (e.g. 4) in the `DyadID` column.

However, I only want observations linked together if they share the same `Condition` value. `Condition` contains three unique values (1, 2, 3). I want condition 1 observations linked with other condition 1 observations, 2 with 2, and 3 with 3.

Importantly, I'd like the students to be linked together randomly.

Ideally, I would like to stay within the tidyverse as that is what I am most familiar with. However, if that's not possible or ideal, any solution would be appreciated.

Here is a possible outcome I am hoping to achieve.

| StudentID | Condition | XP | DyadID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 16 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 12 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 22 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 16 | NA |
| 7 | 1 | 18 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 | 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | 14 | 4 |
| 10 | 1 | 17 | NA |

Note that two students did not receive a pairing, because there was an odd number in condition 1 and condition 3. If there is an odd number, the DyadID can be NA.

Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: In questions like these, when it's not entirely clear what you want to acheive nor how, try solving your problem with *pen and paper*. Simply try to generate a solution by hand, drawing tables and boxes and whatnot, and then see if you can implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @RonakShah. I've updated the posting with the suggestions you made. Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: @MrGumble I will try that approach, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `match` to get a unique id according to `Condition` and `sample` for randomness.

```
library(dplyr)

df_sim <- df_sim %>% mutate(dyad_id = match(Condition,sample(unique(Condition))))
```

Comment: This is close! This provides a shared value in dyad_id for all students in the same condition. However, I want to create pairs of two, such that a dyad_id value is only shared by two students.